# PHP variable as table name mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm working on at function that should be able to handle multiple tables, using `$variables`.

But I get an syntax error..

The code that works.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table_com (tableID, komNAME, komDATE, komHTML, komSTATUS) 
VALUES ('$pID','$name','$time','$kom','$status')";
if(!$mysqli->query($query)) { die($mysqli->error); }
```

and the code that don't

```
$sID = 'table':
$query = "INSERT INTO '$sID'_com ('$sID'ID, komNAME, komDATE, komHTML, komSTATUS) 
VALUES ('$pID','$name','$time','$kom','$status')";
if(!$mysqli->query($query)) { die($mysqli->error); }
```

It is only the table and column `$variables` that don't work..
Here is the my_sql_error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''diy'_com ('diy'ID, 
komNAME, komDATE, komHTML, komSTATUS) VALUES ('1','cjkm,','1' at line 1
```

Are there any way around this problem?

Comment: It's another topic really, but an important one: Please be extra careful escaping those Vars. If possible, use PDO w/ prepared statements to avoid the danger of SQL injections.

Comment: @Fusselwurm [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) can prepare statements too, it's not neccessary to use PDO if he's using mysqli.

Comment: Thanks Richard A - You just saved my day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$query = "INSERT INTO '$sID'_com ('$sID'ID, komNAME, komDATE, komHTML, komSTATUS) 
VALUES ('$pID','$name','$time','$kom','$status')";
```

into

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `{$sID}_com` ({$sID}ID, komNAME, komDATE, komHTML, komSTATUS) 
VALUES ('$pID','$name','$time','$kom','$status')";
```

This way `$sID` will be parsed seperately from `_com`.

I made an example [here](http://3v4l.org/gllmW).

Code:

```
$sID = 'something';
echo "INSERT INTO `{$sID}_com` ({$sID}ID, komNAME, komDATE, komHTML, komSTATUS) 
    VALUES ('pID','name','time','kom','status')";
```

Result:

```
INSERT INTO `something_com` (somethingID, komNAME, komDATE, komHTML, komSTATUS) VALUES ('pID','name','time','kom','status')
```

*Please note that I removed the variables for the parser's sake.*

Comment: It's important to know that table or column names should also be escaped, or must be sanitized. They allow way less legal characters, and there is no API-supplied escaping function for them, so always proceed with caution attempting to create these kinds of dynamic queries! Note also that prepared statements will not help here, as they'll allow only data to be passed - the query itself has to be dynamically constructed as well, and this is where sql injection might happen.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of database design is wrong. $sID should be a field in one single table, not table name.

Please redesign your multiple-table setup to one table where $sID used to identify particular category. It will save you not a day but weeks of pain.

Comment: Hi. Can you give me an eksample? i'm fairly new to this so every hint counts.